# how to get recent registered author id?

Tags: users

I have tried to get the recently registered author user ID. i have no code now, because the below code can't use role to filter it.

```
SELECT max(ID) FROM $wpdb->users LIMIT 1
```

and `get_users`function can get list of the users.

not sure.how to obtain results.

Comment: By registered date! Most recent date should belong to last added user!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need any SQL queries.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'role'         => 'author', // authors only
    'orderby'      => 'registered', // registered date
    'order'        => 'DESC', // last registered goes first
    'number'       => 1 // limit to the last one, not required
);

$users = get_users( $args );

$last_user_registered = $users[0]; // the first user from the list

echo $last_user_registered->ID; // print user ID
```

[Here you can find complete information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) on how to use `get_users()` function.

Comment: I am bit late, I was just typing same :P